# Filter information in two columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, worksheet-function, input-filtering

I need a hint is solving Excel task. I have two columns with data (let's say column A contains a list of people I have met in May; column B a list of people I am planning to meet in June).

Is there a function in Excel which will compare both columns and give me a list of people whom I have met in May but who are not included in the list of planned meetings in June, and show results in column C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With data like:

[image]

In **D1** enter:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,B:B,0)),1,"")
```

and copy down and then in **C1** enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(ROW(),D:D,0)),"")
```

and copy down.  This results in:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, but a combination of functions achieves the result. Please try:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(A1,B:B,0),A1)
```

copied down to suit.

If the name is not listed in ColumnC then a number should be returned that indicates the position in ColumnA where the name is present in addition to in ColumnB.

[IFERROR](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Iferror.html)
[MATCH](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/match.php)

Comment: To show only the names: `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,B:B,0)),A1,"")`